# How can I make Excel conditionally highlight cells based on the contents of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have a few things that I would like to do on Excel:

1. How do you highlight a row [A-U] if only the first cell A has had text entered in it?
    When you enter text in cell A cells B-U have a yellow background?
2. How do you make the highlighting disappear as you fill the cells?
    When you enter text in any of the B-V cells, they return to the white background?
3. How do you make certain cells not have a yellow background with a key word?
    When you enter "Cats" in cell G, cell H returns to the white background as well as cell G.
4. How do you apply this to the entire Excel sheet?

Comment: The feature you want is conditional formatting. You might want to read [this Office help file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the rules. If you'd like them for the entire sheet then simply extend the range (Applies to)...

```
=IF($G1="Cats",TRUE,FALSE)
=ISTEXT(B1)
=NOT(ISBLANK($A1))
```

Please note that the order is important

[image]